# Velocity: First Argument was not a property map

Tags: javascript, typescript, velocity.js

I am using Velocity to do some animations (without jQuery), and I am having an issue where I get the following error:

> Velocity: First argument ([object HTMLDivElement]) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect. Aborting.

I have looked at other examples, and they seem to do it the same way I do, and thiers works. Why is mine not working?

When I dump out the value of `rev.elem` I get a `HTMLDivElement`

```
Velocity(rev.elem, 'slideUp', {
    duration: 225,
    queue: false,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
```

This guy seems to use it the same way and it works for him:
http://jasonweaver.name/blog/velocity-js-vertical-slide-without-jquery

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work by importing both velocity and velocity ui:

```js
import Velocity from 'velocity-animate';
import 'velocity-animate/velocity.ui';
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the beta Velocity V2 then this won't work yet - I removed the shortcuts such as this in favour of an extensible API - I'm working on sequences right now and will return to this answer when they are in there (within the next few weeks).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the [example of this up and running](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWoxmR)...

The example is based on Jason Weaver's original example but has been updated to the latest version of Velocity and has the PUG syntactical error fixed.

```
  var el = document.querySelector(element), // cache click target
    con = document.querySelector(container), // cache container target
    up = 'slideUp', // store up command
    down = 'slideDown'; // store down command

  el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    var active = el.classList.contains('active'); // store active state
    el.classList.toggle('active'); // toggle click target active

    Velocity(con, active ? up : down, { // test and init command
      duration: duration, // duration set in function call params
      easing: easing // easing set in function call params
    });

    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import both "velocity" and "velocity ui":

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@1.5.2/velocity.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@1.5.2/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
```